# How is $ss^{-1}$ idempotent in an inverse monoid?

Tags: abstract-algebra, inverse-semigroups

An inverse monoid S is a monoid such that for all $s \in S$, there exists a $t \in S$ such that $s=sts$ and $t=tst$. In this case, we write $t = s^{-1}$.

Why is $ss^{-1}$ an idempotent? I don't understand how $(ss^{-1})^2 = ss^{-1}ss^{-1} = ss^{-1}$ when $ss^{-1}$ is not guaranteed to be the identity element.

Comment: Use $ss^{-1}s = s$ (which is just $sts = s$, rewritten using $s^{-1} = t$).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Well, I feel stupid now. Thanks. I see it.

Comment: The notation $s^{-1}$ bothers me but I know nothing about this field so maybe it's not confusing in context.

Comment: Don't worry. I find the $s^{-1} $ just as scary as you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(ss^{-1})^2=ss^{-1}ss^{-1}=(ss^{-1}s)s^{-1}=ss^{-1}$, where the last step is according to the definition of inverse.

Answer (score 3):

I'll keep the notation $t$ for $s^{-1}$. You have to prove $(st)(st)=st$. But
$$(st)(st)=(sts)t=st. $$